# node.js and ejs variable not showing at page refresh

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, ejs

I'm trying to pass variable from js to .ejs template file. The values are coming at page first opening but not showing at refresh page. When I log variables, they are seem in console at every refresh.

ejs:

```
<input type="text" value="<%= userfb.testTarget %>" data-min="<%= userfb.testMin %>" data-max="<%= userfb.testMax %>" data-fgcolor="#157fa2" class="dial ringtarget">
```

app.js

```
var query = firebase.database().ref('/doctors/patients/' + request.id + "/testResults");
    query.once("value")
      .then(function(snapshot) {
        snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
            var resultData = childSnapshot.val();
            var testid= resultData.testid;
             console.log("testid:"+testid);

            //Setting Test Results
            // Loop through users in order with the forEach() method. The callback
            // provided to forEach() will be called synchronously with a DataSnapshot
            // for each child:
                  var childData = childSnapshot.val();
                  console.log(childData.testResultValues);
                  var testResultValues =[];
                  for (i in childData.testResultValues) {
                    testResultValues.push(childData.testResultValues[i].value);
                  }
                  userfb.testResultValues=testResultValues;
                  console.log(testResultValues);        


            //Getting test informations      
            var testquery = firebase.database().ref('/doctors/tests').orderByChild("testID").equalTo(testid);
            testquery.once("value")
              .then(function(snapshot2) {
                  snapshot2.forEach(function(snapshot2) {
                      var testData = snapshot2.val();
                      userfb.testName=testData.testName;  
                      userfb.testMax=testData.limitValues.max; 
                      userfb.testMin=testData.limitValues.min; 
                      userfb.testTarget=testData.normalValues.Female; 
                      console.log("testmax:"+userfb.testMax);
                  });
            });   


        });

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution:

I divided the return values (as userfb and testInformations) for each firebase query and now working with refresh page.

```
var query = firebase.database().ref('/doctors/patients/' + request.id + "/testResults");
query.once("value")
  .then(function(snapshot) {
    snapshot.forEach(function(childSnapshot) {
        var resultData = childSnapshot.val();
        var testid= resultData.testid;
         console.log("testid:"+testid);

        //Setting Test Results
        // Loop through users in order with the forEach() method. The callback
        // provided to forEach() will be called synchronously with a DataSnapshot
        // for each child:
              var childData = childSnapshot.val();
              console.log(childData.testResultValues);
              var testResultValues =[];
              for (i in childData.testResultValues) {
                testResultValues.push(childData.testResultValues[i].value);
              }
              userfb.testResultValues=testResultValues;
              console.log(testResultValues);        


        //Getting test informations      
        var testquery = firebase.database().ref('/doctors/tests').orderByChild("testID").equalTo(testid);
        testquery.once("value")
          .then(function(snapshot2) {
             testInformations = snapshot2.val()
              snapshot2.forEach(function(snapshot2) {
                  var testData = snapshot2.val();
                  testInformations.testName=testData.testName;  
                  testInformations.testMax=testData.limitValues.max; 
                  testInformations.testMin=testData.limitValues.min; 
                  testInformations.testTarget=testData.normalValues.Female; 
                  console.log("testmax:"+testInformations.testMax);
              });
        });   


    });

});
```